# link my own show entries box to the data-table

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc.jquery.datatables

I created a show entries box but I don't know how to link it to the data table so it renders the number that is selected. I am doing this to fix the location of the box by using css and js, reading their documents wasn't very helpful to me. thank you. 
this is my select box code:

I tried:
.pageLength
.lengthMenu
.plengthMenu in the script

```
<div class="fixedd" style="color: azure">
Show Entries: &nbsp;<select name="showentries" type="select" 
id="showentries" placeholder="Search...." style="        color: black">
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
</select>
</div>
```

> and this is my script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var dataTable = $('#scrape').dataTable({
            "pageLength": 100,
            "bLengthChange": false,
        });

        $("#searchbox").keyup(function () {
            dataTable.fnFilter(this.value);
        });
         $("#showentries").keyup(function () {
            datatable.lengthMenu(this.value);
        });


    });
```

by the way the search box works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i did to make it work. However it works only on IE if anyone has an idea on how to make it work on chrome feel free to comment or add answer.

```
<div class=" fixedd" style="color: azure">
        Show Entries: &nbsp;<select name="showentries" type="select" id="showentries" placeholder="Search...." style="color: black">
            <option id="_10" value="10">10</option>
            <option id="_25" value="25">25</option>
            <option id="_50" value="50">50</option>
            <option id="_100" value="100">100</option>

        </select>
    </div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
            var dataTable = $('#scrape').dataTable({
               // "pageLength": 100,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                   fixedHeader: {
                    header: true,
                    footer: true,
                    headerOffset: 50
                },
            });
            var table = $('#scrape').DataTable();

            $("#searchbox").keyup(function () {
                dataTable.fnFilter(this.value);
            });
           //'.btn-details',
            $("#scrape").on('click', function () {
                table.page.len(10).draw();
            });
            $("#scrape").on('click', function () {
                table.page.len(25).draw();
            });
            $("#scrape").on('click', function () {
                table.page.len(50).draw();
            });
            $("#scrape").on('click', function () {
                table.page.len(100).draw();
            });
        });
</script>
```